# Why my MariaDB query takes so long? How can I fix it?

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
SELECT 
    ps_customer.id_customer
    CONCAT(ps_customer.firstname," ",ps_customer.lastname) AS "Fullname"
    ps_customer.email
    ps_customer.date_add
    ps_orders.id_order
    ps_orders.id_address_delivery
    ps_orders.payment
    ps_stripepro_transaction.status
    ps_order_detail.id_shop
    ps_order_detail.product_name
    ps_address.address1
    ps_address.address2
    ps_address.postcode
    ps_address.city
    ps_address.phone
    ps_address.phone_mobile
    ps_vd_customer_dogs.name
    ps_vd_customer_dogs.size
    ps_vd_customer_dogs.breed
    ps_vd_customer_dogs.toy_destroyer
    ps_order_cart_rule.name
    ps_order_cart_rule.value
    ps_order_detail.product_quantity
    ps_message.message
FROM ps_orders
    LEFT JOIN ps_customer
    ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer 
    LEFT JOIN ps_stripepro_transaction
    ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_stripepro_transaction.id_order
    LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail
    ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order
    LEFT JOIN ps_address
    ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_address.id_customer
    LEFT JOIN ps_vd_customer_dogs
    ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_vd_customer_dogs.id_customer
    LEFT JOIN ps_order_cart_rule
    ON ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_cart_rule.id_order
    LEFT JOIN ps_message
    ON ps_orders.id_customer = ps_message.id_customer
ORDER BY ps_orders.id_order DESC
```

This is my query. If I shorten it and reduce it to the first 4 left joins, I get the results in 10 min, but when I add the other joins I have to wait over 3 hours.

How can I improve this? My objective is to create a CSV with all the data I'm selecting so that we can improve many people's job in my office who have to check many parameters for each client in our PrestaShop backoffice.

Comment: Are there any indexes on columns used in joins?

Comment: How many "orders" are there?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Can you also include the result of `explain` in order to check the execution plan?